# Copy directory tree without empty directories?

Tags: unix, filesystems, rsync, synchronization

I have the following tree

```
# upper letters = directory
# lower letters = files
A
|-- B
|-- C
    |-- D
    |-- e <= file
|-- F
    |-- G
```

I need to copy this tree to another destination, recursively ignoring all the empty directories. So the destination ends up looking like:

```
C
|-- e
```

How would you do this with unix, rsync, etc?

Answer (score 54):

Of course minutes later I discover an easy method. `rsync` has a `--prune-empty-dirs` option.

Comment: Shortcut : `-m`

Answer (score 1):

There are various solutions to this problem (Taken from [this web page](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-copy-directory-structure-without-the-files-in-linux/)):

This option uses the mkdir command with the find command. This method also requires that you be inside the source folder while executing the command.

```
bash$ cd /path/to/source && find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /path/to/dest/{} ;
```

---

Using find and cpio

```
bash$ find /path/to/source -type d | cpio -pd /path/to/dest/
```

---

Using Rsync

`bash$ rsync -a --include '*/' --exclude '*' /path/to/source /path/to/dest`

OR

`bash$ rysnc -a -f"+ */" -f"- *" /path/to/source /path/to/dest`